# C++ mapi outlook call to ResolveMessageClass fails randomly?

Tags: c++, outlook, mapi

I am working on my outlook plugin using C++ MAPI.
On one particular button click I want to open New Mail window for which I am following below approach. But to my surprise, IMAPIFormMgr::ResolveMessageClass() function fails. That too randomly. At times it works fine and at other times it fails. Couldn't figure out what could be the cause for the same.
Any pointer, idea?

My code flow is something like below
Note: It's not full code, just little bit of overview.

I have printed all the variables and poiters in my log fine and non of them is NULL or garbage or like.

Still it fails at ResolveMessageClass() function only. That too strangely it fails randomly. many a time it works like champ and suddenly it shows some error in ResolveMessageClass()

## Code

```
CComPtr<IMessage> mapiMessage;
hRes = spOutboxFolder->CreateMessage(&IID_IMessage, 0, &mapiMessage);

CComPtr<IMAPIFormInfo> pFormInfo;

std::wstring szMessageClass(L"IPM.Note");

hRes = pFormMgr->ResolveMessageClass(
     wstringTostring(szMessageClass).c_str(), // Message class is ALWAYS ANSI --> Never Unicode
    0,
    spOutboxFolder.get(),
    &pFormInfo);

CComPtr<IPersistMessage> pPersistMessage;

hRes = pFormMgr->CreateForm(NULL, 0L, pFormInfo, IID_IPersistMessage, (LPVOID*)&pPersistMessage);

ULONG_PTR ul = 0;

hRes = spSession->PrepareForm(NULL, mapiMessage, &ul);

hRes = spSession->ShowForm(
                            NULL, //(ULONG)parent->GetSafeHwnd(),
                            msgStore,
                            spInboxFolder.get(),
                            NULL,
                            ul,
                            NULL,
                            MAPI_POST_MESSAGE,
                            pPropsMsg[MSG_STATUS].Value.l,
                            pPropsMsg[MSG_FLAGS].Value.l,
                            pPropsMsg[MSG_ACCESS].Value.l,
                            pPropsMsg[MSG_CLASS].Value.lpszA);
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If your code is in an Outlook addin, why not use OOM to create and display message? In this particular case, using MAPI does not buy you anything.

Comment: Thanks Dmitry, But I don't know about OOM. What is that and how to use it? Any example any website which can help me for OOM?

Comment: Your code is already in a COM addin, right? That means you have a pointer to the Application object from the OnConnection callback, you can use Application.CreaterItem(0) / MailItem.Display().

Answer (score 0):

Use the Outlook object model instead of Extended MAPI. Creating a COM add-in involves two major steps:

- Implement the `IDTExtensibility2` interface in a class module of a dynamic link library (DLL).
- Register the COM add-in.

The key to understanding COM add-in development is the IDTExensibility2 interface. This interface is used by all Office applications to communicate with a COM add-in. This ensures a common initialization mechanism and an ability to pass in the application's object model so that the COM add-in can communicate with the Office application. Listing 23-1 shows the IDTExtensibility2 interface.

```
public interface IDTExtensibility2
{
 void OnAddInsUpdate(ref System.Array custom);
 void OnBeginShutdown(ref System.Array custom);
 void OnConnection(object Application,
 Extensibility.ext_ConnectMode ConnectMode,
 object AddInInst, ref System.Array custom);
 void OnDisconnection(Extensibility.ext_DisconnectMode RemoveMode,
 ref System.Array custom);
 void OnStartupComplete(ref System.Array custom);
}
```

As you can see the `OnConnection` method gets an instance of the host application instance. So, that is where you could start from developing your add-in.

Read more about the OOM in the [Outlook object model overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/outlook-object-model-overview?view=vs-2019) section of MSDN.